# Problem for install Catalina with Catalina patcher

Tags: install, catalina

i have this problem with my mac pro 5,1 2009 This copy of the Install macOS Catalina application is damaged with catalina patcher do you have any issue? a tutoriel? If you can help me it's nice! thx

Comment: Catalina will not run on your machine https://www.apple.com/uk/macos/how-to-upgrade/#hardware-requirements

Comment: i know i make it with Catalina Patcher...